# How to use component as a route in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js

I would like to build something similar to what Facebook has, a popup with dynamic content inside (image, text, etc.). So when you would click on an item it would open up a popup and url would be something like `/post/343542`.

I already have a component which shows up and displays the data, I'm struggling with router part of it. How to use a component in a route?

Thanks!

Comment: Check if this is of any help.
https://dev.to/toomuchdesign/contextual-routing-and-modal-routes-in-next-js-18fn

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to this where I wanted a button onClick event to render an "AddPostComponent" while navigating to a different path.

The way I achieved this was to create a dynamic route under the pages directory.

For example:

```
pages/posts/[id]/index.tsx
```

That [id] would be the reference id of the card you clicked on. Hence it would look like `.../posts/343542/`

You would then do whatever you needed like open/popup that component within the index.tsx file